# Como modelar um sistema de amigos com MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou criando uma pequena rede social e preciso criar a parte das amizades.

Tenho duas ideias:

1. Uma collection Amizades contendo os campos remetente, destnatário e resposta e fazer um `populate` com o mongoose.
2. Colocar um objeto Amigo dentro do documento usuário contendo os amigos daquele usuário e fazer um `populate` com o mongoose.

Qual destas há um melhor desempenho? Ou existe uma outra maneira mais eficaz?